# ionic serve compile even when I have not saved the changes on Ionic2

Tags: typescript, webpack, ionic2

Well, I want compile only when I saved the changes, but Ionic2, compile all time and it takes around 1 minute... so this is very bad.

How I can compile only when file is saved?
I trying with the property `compileOnSave` as `true` on file `tsconfig.json` but this not work as I want.

Comment: are you using live reload?

Comment: I'm using command `ionic serve` without param `--livereload`

Comment: why don't you like live reload?

Comment: Sampath, because it work with or without --livereload... maybe it is a bug

Comment: No, my question is this.When you use live reload, compilation is a background task.So then why you should worry about it? even it happened before save or after it?

Comment: What do you mean by `save the changes`? As in save the files? Isn't that what livereoload does.

Comment: sorry for my english. Well, when I edit(but don't save file changes), ionic re-compile all, and it takes around one minute. So, my idea is set allow compiler only when file is change(after save).
In my case, I'm using OSX Sierra, 16GB RAM, 2.9 GHz Intel Core i5